# PostgreSQL Foreign Table Error Relation Doesn't Exist

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I've created a foreign table `urltrackerft`

In my foreign server `util` it has table `urltracker`:

[image]

[image]

I've followed the steps in creating the foreign server and table here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html

My create script looks something like this:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE urltrackerft (
    id numeric NOT NULL,
    ...
) SERVER util
OPTIONS (schema_name 'util', table_name 'urltracker');
```

But when I try to read the `urltrackerft` table I get this error message:
[image]

To me it looks like perhaps the Foreign server isn't exactly synced.

Checking the user mappings, the info looks correct, could it be the host isn't an IP and is a DNS?
[image]

Perhaps the `firewall` or the `hba_conf` is incorrect for one of the server. But I'm seeing the foreign server `util` in the primary server. I'm a bit lost on this one. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

The primary server is on PostgreSQL v10, and the foreign server is on PostgreSQL v11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your foreign table seems to be in the schema `public` of database `util`, if I read your colorful pictures right.

Then it is unsurprising that the following foreign table definition will not work:

```
OPTIONS (schema_name 'util', table_name 'urltracker')
```

Use `schema_name 'public'` instead.